# Cannot add a row to the the Posgres using EF based .Net Core 3.1 (API project)

Tags: .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have been fighting with EF based on .Net Core 3.1 and PostgreSQL 12. The main problem is that I cannot add a row using the EF. It always wants to get a primary key. I have a baseClass where I have one property - "Id" that has a [Key] attribute. All other entities are inherited from baseClass to get the Id property by default.
Also I created Generic repository to work with any repo in one place. It has the following methods inside like Create, Update, Delete and GetAll. Right now I can get any data from the database but it's not possible to insert any row into the any table as the EF wants to get a primary key.
Below you can see the exception.

```
Unable to track an instance of type 'ProjectData' because it does not have a primary key. Only entity types with primary keys may be tracked.
```

Please advice what to do!

Comment: Could you please post the code of your `ProjectData` class and the code of your base class that ProjectData extends?

Comment: It should be with no problem, refer to [this](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/3170) Could you please show us the related models and your DbContext.

Answer (score 1):

Until now this is an open issue on Entity Framework: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework.Docs/issues/898

You can not add new entities on a DbQuery or an DbSet with no key. I suggest you to keep track on this issue and for now mock your Context or to use Entity Framework Core Mock to accomplish that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was resolved!
**Migrations in the solution must be created. And only then it will be working fine.**